# elasticsearch gets older than indexes (indices)

Tags: elasticsearch

My indexes are created once in a day.
I want to monitor when an index is not created (base on the create.date).

do we have an API call, like the "cat", that can give me all the indexes that are older than x days?

I have n example of a cat API call, that gives me all the indices and their creation date:

```
curl http://10.20.0.147:9200/_cat/indices?h=h,s,i,id,p,r,dc,dd,ss,creation.date.string&s=creation.date
```